# Login to Drupal website from external website through Webservice module

Tags: services

I have a drupal website say www.example.com I have created a REST service service1 using service module.
So i am able to authenticate the user by posting post data username and password to www.example.com/service1/user/login using a form from external site

After after clicking submit from external website, the page remains at http://example.com/service1/user/login with blank page

Now what i want is to redirect the user to home page www.example.com after successful authentication